# Looping while performing work without blocking UI

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

The built-in progress reporter allows for a UI element to be updated, while also running on the thread pool (ref [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html)). This is perfect for occasional updates to a UI element, and all examples I've found showcase that scenario.

However, I need to continuously update a WPF UI element while the CPU-bound work is running, so that it 'loops' through a message in this way until the work is finished:

Running
Running.
Running..
Running...
Running

How can this be accomplished without blocking the UI thread?

Here's the current implementation:

```
internal async Task<bool> FireWithStatusAndWork(IProgress<string> progress) {
    var reportedProgress = "Running";

    bool continueReporting = true;
    bool workStarted = false;

    // loop through the message, but also do background work
    while (continueReporting) {
        if (!workStarted) {
            workStarted = true;
            await Task.Run(() => { model.CPUIntensiveWork(); }).ConfigureAwait(false);
            continueReporting = false;
        }
        progress.Report(reportedProgress);
        if (reportedProgress.Length < 10) reportedProgress += "."; else reportedProgress = "Running";
        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I apologize for yet another async newbie question, but I'm trying to learn from both a philosophical standpoint (proper use for some scenarios but not for others) as well as a practical one (just get the thing running).

I have looked through [MS docs for TAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap)... but if I've missed something pertinent I would be grateful if that were provided as a learning point.

Comment: Do not mix `Thread.Sleep(200);`, use `await Task.Delay(200)` instead

Comment: recheck the logic of that function. I don't think it does what you think it does.

Comment: the `Thread.Sleep` is for visual effect - without it, the message looping looks a little crazy

Comment: @Nkosi i maybe i should have been more clear - the current implementation does not work. indeed it doesn't do what i think it does - or should do at least

Comment: step through the code. That loop is only going to go once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop will only ever run once, given that you are `await`ing the `Task`. Rather than waiting for the task to complete at once, you should create the task and check for its status periodically.

Something like this should work:

```
internal async Task<bool> FireWithStatusAndWork(IProgress<string> progress) 
{
    var reportedProgress = "Running";

    var task = Task.Run(() => model.CPUIntensiveWork());

    while (!task.IsCompleted)
    {
        progress.Report(reportedProgress);

        if (reportedProgress.Length < 10) 
        {
            reportedProgress += "."; 
        }
        else 
        {
            reportedProgress = "Running";        
        }

        await Task.Delay(200);
    }

    return true;
}
```